# Get the path of an audio file in an Intent search

Tags: android, search, audio, path, android-intent

I'm looking for a way to customize my personal Alarm app and i want to choose when i want a different sound for my app browsing the sd audio files.
the core of my code is this:

```
Button butsearch=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonsearch);
    butsearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            mysearch.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            mysearch.setType("audio/*");
            startActivity(mysearch);
        }
    });
```

then android will display me a menu of app for browse the files, i usually choose Music(default) and a list will be displayed (i can listen a preview of the file too) but when i press the OK button i have to preserve the path of the file that i choose. I have to save it in a textview or similar and then in a database for use it in the alarm MediaPlayer.

i tryed  startActivityForResult(mysearch, RESULT_OK);

but what i have to wrote in the body of the method?
i tryed (just for see if it works)

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "result_notok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
       {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "result_ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

}
```

but i can't see the toast.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
File file = new File(YOUR_ALARM_OR_AUDIO_URI);  
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");  
startActivity(intent);
```

learn more about intent : [intent ref.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)

Answer (score 1):

use startActivityForResult (instead of startActivity)